# What is the need of enabling/disabling a module stream?

Tags: linux, rhel, package-management, module

We know that `# dnf module enable <module>:<stream>` helps to enable a stream and `# dnf module disable <module>:<stream>` disables it. Also, `# dnf module reset <module>` resets it so that neither of the stream is enabled/disabled. But... **what is need of doing that?** If i wanna install a particular of stream, I can do that despite it's disabled. Somebody explain?